# How to draw a perpendicular line in Blender in not original 3D Cursor position?

Tags: vertices, edges

I'm not talking about the case when we start playing with Blender and our starting point is at the world origin (0, 0, 0). I am talking about the craziest possibilities. I am having certain hanged in nowhere face and the edge and I need to draw another edge that is perfectly perpendicular to the former. And in the perfect specified length.

Another variation of this question is the case where I have a vertex on some edge and from that vertex, I'm going to draw a perpendicular line to my edge on a certain face. Well... do I have to reposition my cursor?

Thanks for the advice! I am new to Blender!

James Prada

Comment: there are some strict rules in this forum ( i didn't make the rules, but i try to follow them...at least most of them), and one is: pls do only ask one specific question. This rule makes sense because the title is limited and cannot reflect several questions. And others won't find other/multiple questions so ...pls open another question if you have more than one question. Thank you. you may open as many questions as you want.

Answer (score 3):

to make a perpendicular edge to a face you can do this:

1. go to edit mode and select the face
2. create a transform orientation for that face
3. select a vertex
4. Press E (to extrude) and z

for a "perfect length" just type in the lenght, like E Z 2

[image]

Comment: What version of blender are you using? I don't see the plus sign when I open the drop down menu for Orientation.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati: it is at least in all Blender version >= 3.0

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati  In the header: https://imgur.com/a/v1rLzMK

Comment: Oh, found it. Thanks. I was looking at the tool Orientation drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

It's surprising how rarely you will need this, IMO, even in precision modelling. Most set angles are constrained to World or Local XYZ axes, or achieved by segmentation of circles, duplicating existing parts, home-made jigs, etc. ('Thinking like a carpenter').

However, if 'drawing a perpendicular' is 'cutting a face',  then it's worth getting the hang of [the constraints provided by the <kbd>K</kbd> Knife tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html).

To be sure of your moves, it's best, first, to bring yourself to a (<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>) orthographic view  straight down on the face you're cutting, by selecting the face, and hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>.

**To raise a perpendicular from an edge...**

After starting your cut, hit <kbd>A</kbd>, maybe repeatedly. This will toggle between screen-relative and edge-relative angle-constraint. The increment of the constraint defaults to 30°, but you can set your own increment by typing it in while the constraint is active. (You can see the angle and/or length of your cut by hitting <kbd>S</kbd>.)

[image]

**To drop a perpendicular to a target edge...**

..you can create a Custom Orientation from the target edge. (The little '+' top-right in the Transform Orientations pop-up panel from the header). IMO, if you're modelling a lot, it's worth adding that function to your Quick Menu.

With the orientation active, <kbd>K</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> make the cut constrained to its X axis:

[image]

Similar Custom Orientation methods can be used to <kbd>E</kbd> extrude edges or vertices at right-angles to edges defining orientations.